# display NetworkImageView's default image without network request

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I have a ListView displaying things, many of which have an illustrative image and some of which don't. The ViewHolder uses NetworkImageView to display the illustrations.

The problem is that even if a default image is set, it won't be displayed until one calls setImageUrl(), [which in turn will set the source bitmap of the view to null](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr2-release/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java) if the url is empty. If the url isn't empty, it makes a request. This means that one is forced to make a network request even if there isn't a valid network url associated with that particular view, otherwise instead of displaying the default image it displays an empty view.

(issue filed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59538)

Is there a way around making bogus network requests for items without a valid url?

Comment: The best I can come up with so far is swapping out the NetworkImageView with a vanilla ImageView at runtime, which is arguably slightly less inefficient than extra network requests but still inefficient.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
    String url = getURL();
    NetworkImageView niv = (NetworkImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.niv);
    if(url.length() > 0)
        niv.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
    niv.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable._default);
    niv.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.error);
```

Comment: It actually displays the default image even if the url isn't set?

Comment: @Turnsole yep. Make sure are you're using the lasted Volley's code.

Comment: You're right, they already fixed this. I just hadn't pulled the latest version.

Comment: What's the point of extending `ImageView` if they're going to break `setImageDrawable`?

Comment: I use the same code but the default image not shown sometime. Instead it shows the image in xml file. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

For NetworkImageView there is a variable defined named as `mDefaultImageId`
You can use this for defining default image's resource

Here is how you can do it-

Create a file named `attrs.xml`, in that put this lines -

```
<declare-styleable name="DefaultImageResId">
    <attr name="default_image_resource" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Create a class named `CustomNetworkImageView` and use following code -

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.myapp.R;

public class CustomNetworkImageView extends NetworkImageView {
    public CustomNetworkImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDefaultImageResId(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setDefaultImageResId(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setDefaultImageResId(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DefaultImageResId);
        int resId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.DefaultImageResId_default_image_resource, 0);

        if (0 != resId)
            setDefaultImageResId(resId);
    }
}
```

Now in your regular layout xml file use like this -

```
<com.myapp.CustomNetworkImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/img"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:default_image_resource="@drawable/defaultimage"/>
```

Remember, line `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` is very important at the root element of your layout file
Then add `app:default_image_resource`

You are done!!! Now you can even mention image from your xml

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try android:background="yourdrawable"

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/puppy_imageView"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/drawablename"

                    />
```

**UPDATE ANSWER**

after I try this answer I figure the new image will override background so its not good answer

According to documentation **[setDefaultImageResId](http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.html)** can do this

> Sets the default image resource ID to be used for this view until the
>   attempt to load it completes.

simply when you define your

```
NetworkImageView _ImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
_ImageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.yourdrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` is a superclass so use its own setter method to get started:

```
niv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_no_image_avail);   // coerce NetworkImageView to draw itself initially.
```