# How to show place holder and error image from web url in NetworkImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-volley

How to show place holder and error image from web URL in `NetworkImageView` in Volley library. I want to show placeholder and error image from web url following below steps:

1. check in cache for placeholder image
2. if found then show that in imageview
3. else download placeholder image from  web url
4. then show at imageview

Comment: why don't you use Picasso ?

Comment: you can use ImageLoader for NetworkImageView and apply placeholder and error image on this ImageLoader.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display NetworkImageView's default image without network request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567055/display-networkimageviews-default-image-without-network-request)

Comment: I want to display place holder image from a web url (after download from web), I dont want to bundle placeholder image in apk's drawable.

Comment: Please consider taking a look at stackoverflow.com/help for information on how to improve your question. It looks like you haven't done any research on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Please Try like this

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
imageLoader.get("your image path", ImageLoader.getImageListener(
            imgNetWorkView, R.drawable.ico_loading, R.drawable.ico_error));
imgNetWorkView.setImageUrl("your image path", imageLoader);
```

Comment: I want to load "R.drawable.ico_loading, R.drawable.ico_error" from a web URL.